# Intellij IDEA 2018.2 does not recognize the JavaFX packages with JDK 10

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, version

I have searched but not found any detailed information about it. In http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html it says

> As of JDK 7u6 JavaFX is included with the standard JDK and JRE bundles

But I am getting error on compile the code includes `javafx.*` packages. The packages are not founding. I am using Oracle JDK 10.0.2 and Intellij Idea 2018.2. Code is worked after I added the `$JAVA8_HOME/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` as library.

But the strange thing is I am able to build the code to target bytecode version 8 **without adding the jar file from JDK 8** as above.

So the question is

How can I get the latest JavaFX?

Is the latest JavaFX is in the JDK 8?

## UPDATE

JDK 10 includes JavaFX and compiled and ran successfully in command line. There is a problem with Intellij IDEA 2018.2. It does not recognize the JavaFX packages.

The error message in Intellij:

> Error:(3, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist

Note: There is no error while coding in editor (Not underling red). Error occurs when compiling in Intellij.

Updated question title.

Comment: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/java/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html

Comment: I do not use intelliJ, but as per [this post](https://coderanch.com/t/692049/intellij-idea/ide/javafx-working-Java), the "language level" set in your intelliJ settings could be the error.

Comment: IntelliJ does have a confusing array of settings tucked away in dark corners for version of Java, compiler, and code syntax. Add to that settings in Maven, if using that tool. Then layer on Java Modularization being phased in with Java 9 & 10 & 11, and this becomes a stew of challenges to make a Java project build and run.

Comment: @Pagbo Yeah, my problem is same. But the solution in there not worked. The language level must be 10 or 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaFX is included in Oracle JDK up to and including Java 10. From Java 11 onwards it will not be included anymore but can be downloaded separately here http://jdk.java.net/openjfx/ .

Additional information on how to get started with JavaFX from version 11 onwards is also available here: http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafx11/ .

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I see no indication of dropping JavaFX in http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/.  Regardless, “up to and including Java 10” is not completely accurate;  obviously sufficiently old versions did not have JavaFX.

Comment: @VGR https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates

Comment: @VGR That JavaFX was not included before JDK 7u6 was already mentioned by the OP so I did not repeat that. It was also never officially included in the OpenJDK, just to avoid any confusion here.

Comment: This worked to me. I just downloaded the package and included the lib folder in Project Structure - Libraries. Hope iit helps someone

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved with this step:

Set the `Project byte code version` to 10 instead of 8 in

```
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but what does it actually do?

Comment: IntelliJ wasn't recognizing the modules because it was trying to compile to java byte code version 8, even the project SDK was JDK 10. This can provide compatibility of running the compiled program with JRE 8. But JavaFX packages designed with "Java Modules" which was started with JDK 9. Therefore, I needed to tell the IntelliJ to compile to version 10 instead of 8. You can find more information about java modules here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity