# package javafx.util does not exist?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am using openjdk version "1.8.0_252" and I also separately install the javafx and currently the version is javafx.version=11.0.2-internal.
I have added the javafx lib path in the intellij. There is no error while writing the code javafx Pair. However when I build the project with sudo mvn clean install I got build failure with the following error:

```
javafx.util does not exist
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Pair
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225023/intellij-idea-2018-2-does-not-recognize-the-javafx-packages-with-jdk-10

Comment: There are many more things to consider. What - e.g. - does `mvn -version` produce?

Comment: mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_252, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-74-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple. JDK 8 and JFX 11 are just not compatibel with each other. You need at least JDK 11 before you can use any JFX >= 11. I reccommend the latest JFX (14 or even 15 EA, because it contains the most bug fixes) in combination with a JDK >= 11.